# no consecutive even parts

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions, combinatorics-on-words

> A composition of $n$ is an ordered sequence $(a_1,\cdots, a_k)$ so that $\sum_{j=1}^k a_j = n$ and $a_j \in \mathbb{N}\,\forall j$. The $a_j$'s are parts of the composition. Let $c_j$ be the number of compositions of $j$ with no consecutive pairs of even parts. For instance, for $n=4$, the possible compositions would be $(1,1,1,1),(2,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,1,2),(1,3),(3,1),(4).$ Prove that $\sum_{j=0}^\infty c_jx^j = \dfrac{1-x^2}{1-x-2x^2+x^4}$.

I know that in order for there to be no consecutive pairs of even parts, each pair of even parts must be separated by one or more odd parts. Letting $E$ represent an even part and $O$ represent an odd part and $Q+$ represent $1$ or more occurrences of $Q$, and $R^*$ represent $0$ or more occurrences of $R$, each composition seems to be of the form $(EO+)^*$. I know the generating series for the odd natural numbers is $x(1-x^2)^{-1}$ and that of the even natural numbers is $x^2(1-x^2)^{-1}$. How can I determine the set on which the generating series is defined and define the weight function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also start with $0$ or more $O$ or end with $E$: $$O^*(EO+)^*(\epsilon|E)$$

If $f(x)$ is the generating function for $A$, then three basic facts are:

1. The generating function for $A^*$ is $1/(1-f(x))$.
2. The generating function for $A+$ is $f(x)/(1-f(x))$.
3. The generating function for $\epsilon|A$ is $1+f(x)$.

By fact 1, $O^*$ yields generating function $$\frac{1}{1-x(1-x^2)^{-1}}$$

By facts 1 and 2, the generating function for $(EO+)^*$ is:
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2(1-x^2)^{-1}\frac{x(1-x^2)^{-1}}{1-x(1-x^2)^{-1}}}$$

By fact 3, the generating function for $\epsilon|E$ is $1+x^2(1-x^2)^{-1}$.

Putting it all together by multiplication, the final generating function is:
$$\frac{1}{1-x(1-x^2)^{-1}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-x^2(1-x^2)^{-1}\frac{x(1-x^2)^{-1}}{1-x(1-x^2)^{-1}}} \cdot \left(1+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\right)$$

Comment: I had used parentheses just for grouping, not to indicate that $E$ is optional.  I removed them now and updated to use $\epsilon$ for the empty string.

Comment: My bad. I had confused the notation $(\cdot )?$ in regular expressions for the parentheses notation, which doesn't rly make sense.

Comment: You need to be more careful, as your three basic facts only apply to *unambiguous* regular expressions. Thus (1) and (2) are wrong if $A$ is not a code, that is, if $A^*$ is not free and (3) is wrong if $A$ contains the empty word. You also seem to use implicitly a formula for the product, which also requires unambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to start by finding a recurrence for the coefficients $c_n$. Let $C_n$ be the set of compositions of $n$ that do not have two consecutive even parts, so that $c_n=|C_n|$; clearly $c_1=1$, $c_2=2$, $c_3=4$, and $c_4=7$. Suppose that $n\ge 5$, and let $n=a_1+\ldots+a_m$ be a composition in $C_n$.

- If $a_m=1$, $a_1+\ldots+a_{m-1}$ is a composition of $n-1$ in $C_{n-1}$, and every composition in $C_{n-1}$ can be extended to a composition in $C_n$ that ends in $1$.
- If $a_m=2$, $a_1+\ldots+a_{m-1}$ is a composition of $n-2$ in $C_{n-2}$, and every composition in $C_{n-2}$ that ends in an odd number can be extended to a composition in $C_n$ that ends in $2$.
- If $a_m\ge 3$, $a_1+\ldots+a_{m-1}+(a_m-2)$ is a composition of $n-2$ in $C_{n-2}$.

Thus, $c_n$ is $c_{n-1}+2c_{n-2}$ minus the number of compositions in $C_{n-2}$ that end in an even number. If $b_1+\ldots+b_\ell$ is a composition in $C_{n-4}$, then either $b_\ell$ is odd, in which case $b_1+\ldots+b_\ell+2$ is a composition in $C_{n-2}$ that ends in $2$, or $b_\ell$ is even, in which case $b_1+\ldots+(b_\ell+2)$ is a composition in $C_{n-2}$ that ends in an even number greater than $2$. These two possibilities account for all of the compositions in $C_{n-2}$ that end in an even number, so there are $C_{n-4}$ such compositions. Thus, the recurrence is

$$c_n=c_{n-1}+2c_{n-2}-c_{n-4}\,.$$

From this you should be able to work backwards to the generating function.

Comment: sorry I'm new to recurrence relations; I've just learned them. So do I have to solve the characteristic equation $\lambda^4 - \lambda^3 - 2\lambda^2 + 1 = 0$? And then what will be the significance of the roots? Say the roots are $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4.$ Will the solution be of the form $c_n = A\cdot r_1^n + B\cdot r_2^n + C \cdot r_3^n + D\cdot r_4^n$, where $A,B,C,D\in \mathbb{R}$? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FredJefferson: That’s one way to get a closed form for $c_n$, but in this case it would be pretty miserable, since that quartic doesn’t have nice roots. I wasn’t thinking of that: I was just thinking of deriving the generating function. Since you’re not familiar with the technique, I’ll add it to my answer hen I get a bit of time, if only for future reference.